# Read 10 files asynchronously in Spring Boot

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-boot

The code below shows me reading a file one at a time in a folder. I want to read 10 files at once, run through a METHOD_A and write to another folder. There are 5000 files in the folder. Reading the file 1 at a time is extremely slow. I want to speed it up.

I'm using Java Spring Boot. Any suggestions how I can do so?

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
     Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(files[i]));
     JSONObject obj1 = METHOD_A(obj);

        try{
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(...);
            writer.println(obj1);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do something
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a thread executor pool.   I see writing, but no reading, in your example. 
 Why are you writing the contents?  I hope this is just a demo.

Comment: Yeah its just a demo. I see that I can use thread executor pool. Any examples you can provide?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes u can! , Example;

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(/*Number of Threads*/);


    for (int i = 0; i < /* Number of Requests */; i++) {
        WorkerThread wt = context.getBean(WorkerThread.class, String.valueOf(i));
        tasks.add(wt);
    }

    List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);

    for (Future<String> future : futures) {
        String result = future.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide more explanation and apply it to my code? It will go a long way.

Comment: Create a new Class and name it "WorkerThread" with @Component Annotation, implements Callable<String>. In doWork() do your work ;)

Answer (score 2):

Managing threads and tasks should be considered for CPU bound work, which is not your case. For input/output you should use non-blocking IO instead, such as `AsynchronousFileChannel`. The [RxIo](https://github.com/javasync/RxIo) simplifies the AFC use and you may achieve your goal through the [`AsyncFiles`](https://github.com/javasync/RxIo) API, such as:

```
AsyncFiles
      .readAll(files[i])
      .thenApply(parser::parse)
      .thenApply(obj -> obj.toString().getBytes())
      .thenCompose(bytes -> AsyncFiles.writeBytes(..., bytes))
      .thenAccept(index ->     /* invoked on completion */)
      .exceptionally(excep -> /* invoked on error*/
```

Usually to manage asynchronous IO you should use nonblocking IO, which avoids managing threads pools explicitly and blocking threads. Since, the accepted answer proposal is blocking threads to get the result, how many threads will you configure in `newFixedThreadPool(size)` to achieve concurrency?

Maybe, the thread pool size could be equals to the number of files being read. Maybe 10 in your case?

But then in `WorkerThread` proposal you are blocking the thread on read and parse. I am not aware of the type of `parser`, but since you are giving it a blocking `FileReader` then `parser.parse(…)` will block for sure. Finally, you will block again on `writer.println()`.

The following image shows the difference between the accepted answer proposal corresponding to “*synchronous, two threads of control*” and my proposal corresponding to “*asynchronous*”

[image: eloquent javascript]

Answer (score 0):

Base on your requirement I have adding the below codes for you. Try with this and see if working for you. Please keep in mind that your server should have enough number of processors as well for concurrent processes. If you still confuse see one example program at the end:-

```
    private int numberOfFileProcessed = 0;
    private int numberOfThreadAlive = 0 ;
    private int numberOfThreadAlive = 0;
    private int numberOfThreadToBeAllowed = 10;//Change this value to control number of thread to be run concurrently

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
     Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(files[i]));
     JSONObject obj1 = METHOD_A(obj);
     try{
            Thread t = new Thread(new ReadFiles(obj1));
            t.start();
            numberOfThreadAlive++;
        }catch (Exception e) {
        //do something  
       }

      while(numberOfThreadAlive > numberOfThreadToBeAllowed){//This while loop will control number of thread to be not more than 10
        try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception e){}//Release the processor    
      }
  }

  private final synchronized void jobCompleted(){       
            numberOfFileProcessed++;
            numberOfThreadAlive--;      
  }

  while(numberOfFileProcessed < files.length){
    //wait till last thread complete it's task
    //I am not using thread.join() for performance 
    try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception e){}//Release the processor
  }



private class ReadFiles implements Runnable  {
        JSONObject jobj;
        public ReadFiles(JSONObject obj) {
            jobj = obj;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void run() {
          try{      
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(...);
            writer.println(jobj);
            writer.close();
            jobCompleted();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // do something
          }
        }

    }
```

Below is a test file which you can use for understanding

```
        package com.test.threadtest;

    public final class ThreadTest {
        private int numberOfFileProcessed = 0;
        private int numberOfThreadAlive = 0 ;   
        int numberOfThreadToBeAllowed = 10;

        public void processFiles(){

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
                try{
                      Thread t = new Thread(new ReadFiles(i));
                      t.start();
                      numberOfThreadAlive++;
                 }catch (Exception e) {
                    //do something  
                 }

                  while(numberOfThreadAlive > numberOfThreadToBeAllowed){//This while loop will control number of thread to be not more than 10
                    try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception e){}//Release the processor
                    System.out.println("Reached maximum");
                  }
            }  
              while(numberOfFileProcessed < 50){
                //wait till last thread complete it's task
                //I am not using thread.join() for performance 
                  System.out.println("Number of file processed :" + numberOfFileProcessed);
                try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception e){}
              }
        }

        private final synchronized void jobCompleted(){     
                numberOfFileProcessed++;
                System.out.println("numberOfFileProcessed :" + numberOfFileProcessed);
                numberOfThreadAlive--;      
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();
            test.processFiles();
            System.out.println("Exit from the process");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        private class ReadFiles implements Runnable  {
            int i;
            public ReadFiles(int val) {
                i = val;
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void run() {
              try{      
                System.out.println("I am Thread : " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                jobCompleted();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                // do something
              }
            }

        }
    }
```